# simple current source calcuation

Tags: current-source

Which equation defines maximum current sink by Q1 in this circuit ?
Which equation define maximum voltage at V2 at which  Q1  enter linear mode of operation ( f.e.  VCE ~ 0.5V)  ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg4xrr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I consider circuit without the resistor and voltage at collector I can write:

Ic ~ Ie= Ve/R4

When I ignore base current then I get :

Ve = Vb - Ube = R1/(R1+R5)*(5V - UfD1) +UfD1 -Ube

Then with first equation I get:

Ie *Re  = R1/(R1+R5)*(5V - UfD1) +UfD1 -Ube

How to solve these equation in order to get value of sink current by current source ?

---

Comment: What do you think it is? Show us where you're stuck.

Comment: Can you provide any of your thinking, at all? Or are you drawing a complete blank on how to approach this?

Comment: You can replace your \$R_1\$ and \$R_5\$ divider with a Thevenin source and resistance. The Thevenin voltage source and resistance would be: \$V_{TH}=\left( \frac{V_1}{R_1} + \frac{V_{D_1}}{R_5} \right) \cdot \left( R_1\mid\mid R_5\right)\$ and \$R_{TH}=R_1\mid\mid R_5\$. From that and \$V_{BE}\$ and \$R_4\$, you should be able to work out the base and emitter currents (assuming an active mode and not saturated.) Using \$I_C\approx I_E\$, you should get close I think.